# find the difference between a column ion two rows grouped by one and sort by another column

Tags: postgresql

Need to find the sequential difference and average between within a columns of two rows group by brand column and order by bill_id column and find the difference of worth column between rows in a single query.

I have a data

```
brand bill_id worth
Moto    1    2550
Samsung 1    3430
Samsung 2    3450
Moto    2    2500
Moto    3    2530
```

Expected Output

```
brand bill_id worth net_diff avg_diff
Moto    1     2550   0        00
Moto    2     2560   10       5
Moto    3     2540   -20     -5
Samsung 1     3430   0        0
Samsung 2     3450   20       10
```

Comment: Please explain how `worth` is changed from the input to the output; or are you just being inconsistent. Worth input for Moto (2550, 2500, 2530) but output transformed to (2550, 2560, 2540). This transformation does not appear related to anything within the data.

Answer (score 1):

With the following data :

```
CREATE TABLE T (brand VARCHAR(16),  bill_id INT, worth DECIMAL(16,2))
INSERT INTO T VALUES 
('Moto',    1,    2550),
('Samsung', 1,    3430),
('Samsung', 2,    3450),
('Moto',    2,    2500),
('Moto',    3,    2530);
```

One possible solution could be :

```
WITH 
T0 AS
(
SELECT *, worth - COALESCE(LAG(worth) OVER(PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY bill_id), worth) AS net_diff
FROM T
)
SELECT *, AVG(net_diff) OVER(PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY bill_id) 
FROM   T0;
```

But I do not understand the computation formulae of your example for AVG...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by average you are looking for 1/2 the difference between 2 consecutive `bill_id` for a `brand`. You can get this by applying the [lag()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html) function twice (with answer from @SQLpro as a base) arriving at: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wW4Y8-YW))

```
with  bill_net(brand, bill_id, worth,net_diff)  as
      ( select  billing.*, worth - coalesce(lag(worth) over(partition by brand order by bill_id), worth) 
          from billing
      )
select brand, bill_id, worth, net_diff, coalesce(round(((net_diff - lag(net_diff) over(partition by brand order by bill_id))/2.0),2),0.00)  
from   bill_net;
```

**NOTE:** Due to inconsistency between Input and Results it does not exactly produce you expected results.